# Android Firebase Database Check if User is in Group

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, usergroups

Hi searching a lot but cant find any questions who are related with my topic / or was answered.

Im using Firebase Database with these structure (from firebase official documentation)

```
// An index to track Ada's memberships
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

The Docu says: Check if /$uid/groups/$group_id  is null

```
This approach, inverting the data by listing the IDs as keys and setting the value to true, makes checking for a key as simple as reading /users/$uid/groups/$group_id and checking if it is null. The index is faster and a good deal more efficient than querying or scanning the data.
```

But how can i manage this in Java Code?

With something like this?

```
mDatabase.child("table/foo").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //
```

i need a simple true or false after this query

```
if(query) {
user is in Group
... else {
User is not in group
```

Just or better highlighting

key is my userID

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference memberDatabaseReference = rootRef.child("groups").child(groupName).child("members").child(key);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Member does not exist!");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Member exists!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
memberDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `exists()` method on the `dataSnapshot` object. So, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference memberDatabaseReference = rootRef.child("groups").child(groupName).child("members").child(memberName);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Member does not exist!");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Member exists!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
memberDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which `mamberName` is the name of member you want to verify. In this way you can verify the existens of a memeber.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My DB Layout is: Benutzer/$UID/groups/admins(which true or false) and in my Groups  /groups/admins/members/usernames = true   so in your Code i have to use this? [..] = rootRef.child("groups").child("admins").child("members").child("USERID").child(memberName);  what is the memberName?  oh okay, i think MemberName is my userID i will give it a try

Comment: Yes, you need to go down in the tree to reach the group node, where you need to do the verification. So if those are the correct childs, yes, give it a try. `memberName` is the name of memeber you want to verify.

Comment: Okay it works big thanks! Another Question: is this a "fast" solution? In my finally App i have to check this status for about 100 childs (users) i want to display all Childs on a map which are members of my bike group (Users with bike show this map, users with car show an other map)  so my query checks 100+ users, but it works and now i unterstand this .exist() method Thank you =)

Comment: Good to hear that. It's a good solution becase you are checking the members for a specific group. If you want to learn something more complex, i recomand you take a look at this post, [Structuring your Firebase Data correctly for a Complex App](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data).

Comment: @AlexMamo – Alex, so you're downloading every group data and check if the user uid appears in the group members?

Comment: As you see in `memberDatabaseReference`, we are downloading only a particular group, note the entire node (not every group).

Comment: @AlexMamo – hold on, so the best practice to fetch groups given the user uid is to first get user groups (`user/$user_uid/groups/`) and then fetch the group data given the groups I've just fetched? Thank you!

Comment: Depends on what you really want to achieve. All the groups in which the users belongs, or all the users who are apart of a single group. In both cases, you need to do in the way you say.

Answer (score 0):

Make a node in your firebase security like this

```
{
    "rules":{
    "checkIfMemberIsInGroup":{
        "$groupId":{
            "$memberId":{
                ".read":false,
                ".write":"auth != null && !newData.exists() &&
                 root.child('groups').child($groupId).child('members').child($memberId).exists()"
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Then check if user is part of group with lightweight query, and let server takeup bandwidth..

```
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("checkIfMemberIsInGroup")
            .child(groupName)
            .child(memberName)
            .setValue(null, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if (databaseError != null && databaseError.getCode() == DatabaseError.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        // user is not member of group
                    } else {
                        // user is member of group
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try